# Mixing replies in Netty with keep-alive mode

Tags: netty

I've implemented a rest service with netty (HttpResponseEncoder + HttpObjectAggregator) that replies with a json to get/post queries. 
It worked fine while I closed connection after each request. 
But later I've tried to use keep-alive connection with something like

```
private void writeResult(HttpResponseStatus status, ByteBuf buffer, ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    FullHttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, status, buffer);
    response.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    response.headers().setInt(HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_LENGTH, response.content().readableBytes());
    response.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.CONNECTION, HttpHeaderValues.KEEP_ALIVE);
    ctx.writeAndFlush(response);
}
```

Under some load there is a very strange case captured by testing system - sometimes replies are mixed (for example, we ask for entity A /a/123 and receive some reply for entiry B). I was not able to reproduce it using sending requests in browser, for example. 
Once I return to closing connections back all tests are passed.

```
   private void writeResult(HttpResponseStatus status, ByteBuf buffer, ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {    
        FullHttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, status, buffer);
        response.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        response.headers().setInt(HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_LENGTH, response.content().readableBytes());
        response.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.CONNECTION, HttpHeaderValues.CLOSE);
        ctx.writeAndFlush(response).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
}
```

It looks very strange and I expected a bug in my code, but I don't understand why it appears only in keep-alive mode. Are there any hints what could go wrong so I can debug it, because I'm a new in netty so have no idea what could be a reason.

**UPD** Sample error with Netty log:
https://pastebin.com/7V1trGpS

It complains with
 RESPONSE BODY {"avg":2.30769} != {"visits": [{"mark": 4, "visited_at": 958104556, "place": "\u0417\u0430\u043c\u043e\u043a"}]}
(we return average instead of visits list).

But in netty log we can see that avg is returned for request
GET /locations/417/avg?fromAge=7

and for next request 
GET /users/140/visits?toDistance=8 
we return correct visit list.

It is a bit suspicious that these requests are sequential, but I've checked this service with two different checker tools and both of them see no issues when keep-alive is disabled.

Comment: The browser probably connects to your server using [http pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining), this means that the backend server receives multiple requests before it has a time to respond. For most servers this isn't a problem, but when doing async tasks, this can get really annoying to deal with. Most browsers don't use this because some servers are buggy (even if it's allowed by the spec), but most load test programs do

Comment: @Ferrybig, thanks for your comment, but I've checked and was told that http-pipelining is not enabled for this test setup.

Comment: Can you add a `LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO)` to the pipeline for debugging purposes, and then check what exactly happens when the responses get mangled? Notice that pipelining will become more important in the future, and since its part of the protocol, your program should really try to support it

Comment: @Ferrybig, thanks for yor advice with LoggingHandler, it's output is really nice, but still no luck. II've added some details to my post.

Comment: Looking at the log file, I can see all responses are send in the proper order, the only thing that I notice is tht your testing tool wants escaped json (`"place": "\u0417\u0430\u043c\u043e\u043a"`) and your code send normal UTF-8 characters: (`"place":".........."`) (they show as dots inside the log file because netty tries to parse them as ascii, but when you look at the hex numbers, you can see that it's the proper characters